# How do I scrape down a asynchrous JSON variable?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to make a Node.js bot, so I found a module, installed it and tried out its example code.
Now, I have an async function that loads some text from an API. This is the code:

```
(async () => {
    // Display user's balance
    balance = kraken.api('Balance');
    console.log(await balance);
})();
```

When I run the code above, this is what I get in commandprompt:

```
{
    error: [],
    result: { A: '2.0', BC: '0.005', BCA: '111' }
}
```

How would I be able to make it only log a specific part of this, which looks like an array?
I've tried doing stuff like (to get it to return 2.0):

```
console.log(await balance.result.A)
```

But that does not seem to work as it returns this:

```
(node:6604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'A' of undefined
(node:6604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Out of ideas and need help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You habe to put your await statement in parentheses, like this:

```
console.log((await balance).result.A);
```

This will fetch the balance asynchronously, then log the result property.